# XCTest: initialization of protocol variable is showing an error cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: xctest, ios13, xcode11, xctestcase, swift5

I need to access to protocol but I'm getting the following error:

```
'MyProtocol' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

Here is my implementation:

```
public protocol MyProtocol{
    var someVar: Int {set get}
    var anotherVar: String {set get}
}


class ProtocolProjectTests: XCTestCase {
    var myProtocol: MyProtocol!

    override func setUp() {
        self.myProtocol = MyProtocol()
    }
}
```

On this line `self.myProtocol = MyProtocol()` is where I'm getting the error.

My question to you guys is how can initialize the variable in the XCTest class

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some struct/class with this protocol, for example:

```
class MyProtocolMock: MyProtocol{
    var someVar: Int
    var anotherVar: String

    init() {
        someVar = 0
        anotherVar = ""
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
class ProtocolProjectTests: XCTestCase {
    var myProtocol: MyProtocol!

    override func setUp() {
        self.myProtocol = MyProtocolMock()
    }
}
```